# Nginx rewrite with if statement

Tags: nginx

We have CSS file "development.css", but for IE users I need to redirect them to "production.css" instead. There's a location rule for that:

```
location = /css/development.css {
  if ($http_user_agent ~* 'Trident') {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /css/production.css redirect;
  }
}
```

The redirect works for IE correctly, but for all other browsers it's 404. Nginx's "if" doesn't have "else"; what is the correct way to handle ifs with rewrite?

Comment: Please show the _complete_ `server` block. The problem will be somewhere else.

Comment: No it was exactly in this rule. I've added alias with full path to production.css  and it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you to use nginx [map](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html). Something like this (written in the browser, not tested):

```
map $http_user_agent $envtype {
    default       "production";
    "~Trident" "development";
}

rewrite /css/development.css /css/$envtype.css;
```

Comment: This is even better, shorter solution and it works!

Answer (score 1):

So this is the code that works.

```
    location = /css/development.css {
        if ($http_user_agent ~* 'Trident') {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /css/production.css last;
        }
        alias C:/Work/src/css/development.css;
    }
```